# Unable to list drive collections for PointPublishing Hub site using O365 Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Beginning last week, Microsoft Graph functionality has changed when attempting to retrieve `drive` collections for certain types of `sites`.

When attempting to list `drive` collections for a `PointPublishing Hub` site using an App-Only Auth token a `401 unauthenticated` error is returned.

Here is what I see:

I first search for a list of sites in my SharePoint instance:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2015-05-22T17:20:49Z",
            "id": "mysiteid",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "0001-01-01T08:00:00Z",
            "name": "hub",
            "webUrl": "https://mysite/portals/hub",
            "root": {},
            "siteCollection": {
                "hostname": "mysite"
            },
            "displayName": "PointPublishing Hub Site"
        }
    ]
}
```

The site exists and I can actually navigate to it.  It looks like some kind of System site for Office 365 video.

I can retrieve the site metadata using the API:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysiteid

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites/$entity",
    "createdDateTime": "2015-05-22T17:20:49Z",
    "description": "",
    "id": "mysiteid",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-11-25T14:28:55Z",
    "name": "hub",
    "webUrl": "https://mysite/portals/hub",
    "root": {},
    "siteCollection": {
        "hostname": "mysite"
    },
    "displayName": "PointPublishing Hub Site"
}
```

Everything looks fine so far. Now I try get a list of `drive` collections:

```http
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysiteid/drives

{
    "error": {
        "code": "unauthenticated",
        "message": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d7e18e09-858f-41c7-aec2-9c962b9dc446",
            "date": "2017-11-25T14:42:31"
        }
    }
}


client-request-id →d7e18e09-858f-41c7-aec2-9c962b9dc446
request-id →d7e18e09-858f-41c7-aec2-9c962b9dc446
```

Is this now by design or is a regression?  Should I be able to get a list of drive collections for these types of sites?

Comment: I am currently porting one of our code bases for SharePoint Online connectivity over to the Graph API and I am also having this same issue!

Last Wednesday the `/sites/root/drives` endpoint was functioning correctly. Today one of the testers on our QA team reported that it is no longer working.

Comment: I went ahead and filed an [issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2004) on this. @ruelloehr

Answer (score 0):

We did have a regression in drive enumeration when we fixed an issue that was limiting the results to only include `template=DocumentLibrary` instead of `baseType=DocumentLibrary`. If you're still seeing failures with this scenario please let us know with a comment to this answer.